# why Bootstrap 4 Form password field font has a unexpected underline?

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4

**Unexpected underline occurring in the password field font**
and this form is inside a **bootstrap 4 modal**
[image: here is the image]

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username"><u>Username:</u></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" 
        autocomplete="off" autofocus required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
         <label for="password"><u>Password:<u></label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" 
         name="password" autocomplete="off" required>
         <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check">Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <center>
         <button type="submit" name="login-btn" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
    </center>
</form>
```

**HTML code**

```
.form-control,.form-control:focus{
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: white;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.form-check{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.form-check-input{
    margin-top: .4rem;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

**CSS** i applied 
i also tried **text-decoration:none;** and mostly i can say this is **not a border**.input field Border is the white one

Comment: It would be easier if you can post your code too, by default it does not add any underline, must be something specific to your case. Have a look at working demo at http://nicesnippets.com/live/login-form-design-in-bootstrap-4-modal-usign-html-and-css-demo.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please give us the css and the html code for the password field. Also look for the `text-decoration: underline;` css property, set on one of its parent containers.

Comment: i have updated my post with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely due to this line:

```
<label for="password"><u>Password:<u></label>
```

You need to fix the markup and use a closing `</u>`

```
<label for="password"><u>Password:</u></label>
```

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/gjLwxk2v/6/

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Question with code.

Try:

```
style="border: none !important"
```

or:

```
style="text-decoration: none !important"
```

on your input div.